# How do I reset all progress in the game "just shapes and beats"?

Tags: just-shapes-and-beats

The game [just shapes and beats](https://store.steampowered.com/app/531510/Just_Shapes__Beats/) has a very unique intro that I would like to show my friend again for the first time. I'm not sure how to reset all my progress on this game to achieve this though. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The options screen from the main menu has an option to reset your story progress.

Answer (score 1):

In the Title Screen, Press O, then go to the game settings and then go to the Bottom.
There, You will find the Button that says "Reset Game Progress"
Click it and say yes to the Question that pops up and you deleted all your Game Progress!

Answer (score 0):

I found this out relatively quickly, but the answer to reseting all progress is to first turn off cloud saving.

[image: 1]

Then go to `%AppData%\LocalLow\Berzerk Studio\Just Shapes _ Beats` and delete savedata.jsb to reset all progress.

Comment: It’s worth adding on the Switch version you can create a new user profile for the same effect