# How do I delete save data in Just Shapes and Beats?

Tags: just-shapes-and-beats

I recently got *Just Shapes and Beats* and wanted to delete the game progress to start over with my friends. How do I do that?

Comment: That really depends on the platform you're playing it on..

Comment: I'm playing on PC. I checked the options but there's no option to reset the game progress.

Comment: While looking for an answer, I found out it is a possible duplicate of [How do I reset all progress in the game "just shapes and beats"?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/334983/how-do-i-reset-all-progress-in-the-game-just-shapes-and-beats)